# How to recognize new line character (\n) in HTML

Tags: html

I have an application in which I receive a comment string from REST Api like this

```
"comments":"This is a comment\nAnother comment\nOne more\nLast
```

I'm displaying it using p tag but it's not recognizing line breaks(\n). How to have a newline?

Answer (score 15):

It may be an issue of the CSS,

if you apply `white-space: pre-wrap`, then it may help ensure your linebreaks are recognized.

See docs for other `white-space` options & what they do.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```js
const nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

// Replacing the innerHtml because the newline chars aren't acknowledged if I define them in the HTML.
for(let n of nodes) {
  n.innerHTML = 'Here is \nSome example \nText with \nLine breaks.'
}
```

```css
p.no-breaks {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: red;
}

p.with-breaks {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="no-breaks">This text will be replaced.</p>

<p class="with-breaks">This text will be replaced.</p>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! Sure, it's easy to replace "\n" with "<br>" with JS, but then you're probably entering the text from some sort of editor and don't want to allow other HTML through, but you've forced yourself into a situation where you have to filter out HTML then do the replacement yourself. With this, no JS hack is needed. I'm using Vue.js, and didn't want to switch to v-html for the reasons I've just stated. I personally used `pre-line` as I still wanted spaces to collapse.

Answer (score 9):

`<pre>` tag is set to recognize newlines. You can make the `<p>` behave like `<pre>` via CSS but you will loose any HTML in the `<p>` (if there are any).

Alternatively, you have to replace them with HTML linebreak `<br>` or `<br/>`

Comment: but you will loose any HTML in the <p>; I dint get you

Comment: @Protagonist .. As I said, in case of `<pre>`, if there are any. In the example, there weren't any HTML so that was not an issue.

Answer (score 5):

There is two way:

1. If you have access to your REST api. before return comment, Use `nl2br` function (php)
2. You can use below code in JavaScript (JS):

   ```
   var comment = "This is a comment\nAnother comment\nOne more\nLast";
   comment = comment.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
   alert(comment);
   ```

Comment: Whilst this works, beware of dragons - if the text came from a user input where you don't want to allow other HTML, you'll have to clean the text first. Libraries and tools like Vue.js, Lodash, and even jQuery give you a way to set the text instead of setting the HTML, which effectively prevents HTML, but they will also prevent the `br` tags. Using CSS `white-space: pre-line;` achieves the same affect without needing to insert HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want!!

```
var data = '{"comment" : "sometext\\n\\n"}'
```

It worked for me..